# Slipt Toolbar like Gmail tablet app

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I would like to know how to slipt the toolbar action items like Gmail tablet App.
This is a screenshot of Gmail app:
[image]

How can I achieve the same result?
Should I put the toolbar inside each fragments instead of in the activity?

Thanks a lot